# looking for monospaced condensed font

Tags: fonts, typewriter

I am looking for condensed mono spaced (typewriter) fonts to typeset program listings with pdflatex. The fonts should have the common shapes (up and italic or slanted) and series (normal and bold). Any suggestions?

Comment: By "typewriter" font, I assume you mean monospaced, right? Separately, will you be running pdflatex, xelatex, or lualatex?

Comment: @Mico Yes, I mean mono spaced fonts. I will be running pdflatex.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Latin Modern ha a condensed version of the typewriter font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\ttfamily\lipsum[1]

\fontseries{lc}\selectfont
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need the text justified, you have to modify the `\fontdimenX` values

Answer (score 5):

I do not know any free fonts satisfying your requirements.  If you can consider non free fonts. I would recommend  The Sans Mono Condensed Font designed by Lucas de Groot specifically for typesetting program code: http://www.lucasfonts.com/fonts/thesansmono/thesansmono-condensed/.   Years ago I wrote LaTeX support package for it: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thsmc.  Of course XeTeX can use this font directly.

Comment: The Sans Mono Condensed is the same font used by O'Reilly programming books for code listings. Beautiful font.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of looking for condensed fonts, you can also just change the size of the default font. I find that Latin Modern in `\footnotesize` looks quite good in listings:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{%
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,%
  numbers=left,%
  numberstyle=\footnotesize,%
  tabsize=2%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C]
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Latin Modern typewriter font has normal and bold series, but the difference is subtle. You can try passing the `lighttt` option to the `lmodern` package for more distinction.

You can also browse [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/typewriterfonts.html).

Answer (score 4):

There is `beramono`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[scaled=.83]{beramono}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\ttfamily\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```