# How to scale horizontally every character in listings code?

Tags: fonts, listings, tcolorbox, scaling

I want to scale horizuntally every character in listings code, making it narrower. The `basewidth` option is not what I want, since it doesn't scale characters. Any way to achieve this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,tcolorbox,arev}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
Hello \LaTeX{} World! Hello \LaTeX{} World!
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{tcblisting}{listing and text}
Hello \LaTeX{} World! Hello \LaTeX{} World!
\end{tcblisting}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  basewidth = {0.5em,0.45em},
}

\begin{lstlisting}
Hello \LaTeX{} World! Hello \LaTeX{} World!
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{tcblisting}{listing and text,listing options={basewidth = {0.5em,0.45em}}}
Hello \LaTeX{} World! Hello \LaTeX{} World!
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This won't look very good. Are you sure you want this? One way would be to use a narrower font, if you find one.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Only a few fonts have narrow series. It would be another choice for other fonts,

Comment: Distorting fonts like this, to many typeface designers I believe, is a typographical sin that one should never commit. In any case, you may want to use a “condensed” mono-spaced font (for instance, [looking for monospaced condensed font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47489), which would make this post a duplicate)

Comment: Apart from Latin Modern Mono Condensed, there are [Envy Code R](https://damieng.com/blog/2008/05/26/envy-code-r-preview-7-coding-font-released), [Monoid](https://larsenwork.com/monoid/) and [Iosevka](http://typeof.net/Iosevka/). According to their licenses, they are free to use. The latter three require XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX of course. Monoid and Iosevka support code ligatures. Iosevka has a large number of weights (and shapes).

Comment: @RuixiZhang Fun anecdote: For *Serif* issue 1, I used a slightly condensed version of Lucida Sans for figure captions. Kris Holmes, when I gave her a copy, immediately saw what I did. She did agree, though, that a proper Lucida Sans condensed would be a good idea, but it never did materialize. (personally, I find condensed less offensive than expanded—in the early days of 16:9 TVs, if a 4:3 image was expanded to fill the screen, the distorted type always made me a little nauseated).

Answer (score 2):

This approach is not `listings` and thus it has no character highlighting, for example.  Rather, it is `tokcycle`, and what I do here is the unpardonable sin of manually condensing a font (mea culpa!).  I also eliminate those pesky spaces following detokenized macros, except of course, if a cat-11 token follows.

The first 3 lines show successively compressed listings

The 4th example demonstrates auto-line breaking.

Finally, in the 5th example, I show how the method can be joined with `\obeylines` and/or `\obeyspaces` to get listing linebreaks  and/or spaces that follow the source code.

As you can see, the method, even as it takes an argument, is verbatim-like.  However, it still requires balanced braces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,tokcycle}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newsavebox\sptok
\sbox\sptok{ }
\newif\ifmacro
\newcommand\altdetok[2]{\begingroup\stripgroupingtrue\macrofalse
  \stripimplicitgroupingcase{-1}%
  \tokcycle
    {\ifmacro\def\tmp{##1}\ifcat\tmp A\scalebox{#2}[1]{ }%
      \fi\allowbreak\macrofalse\fi
     \scalebox{#2}[1]{\string##1}}
    {\ifmacro\macrofalse\fi\{\processtoks{##1}\}\allowbreak}
    {\tctestifx{\par##1}{\\}{%
     \allowbreak\scalebox{#2}[1]{\string##1}\macrotrue
    }}
    {\hspace{#2\wd\sptok plus 3em minus .3ex}}
    {#1}\endgroup}
\catcode37=12
\newcommand\narrowdetok{\catcode37=12\narrowdetokaux}
\catcode37=14
\newcommand\narrowdetokaux[2][1]{\par\noindent
  \altdetok{#2}{#1}\catcode37=14\par}
\begin{document}
\narrowdetok{Today is \today and \today! Here is a 
  \rule{1em}{1ex}.}

\narrowdetok[.8]{Today is \today and \today! Here is a 
  \rule{1em}{1ex}.}

\narrowdetok[.6]{Today is \today and \today! Here is a 
  \rule{1em}{1ex}.}

\noindent\hrulefill

\narrowdetok[.7]{Today is \today! Here is a \rule{1em}{1ex}. 
  I will    continue with this &^#$%\ listing to see if it 
  autobreaks at each line or if it obeys lines.

New paragraph.}

\noindent\hrulefill\obeylines\obeyspaces
\narrowdetok[.7]{Today is \today! Here is a \rule{1em}{1ex}. 
  I will    continue with this &^#$%\ listing to see if it 
  autobreaks at each line or if it obeys lines.

New paragraph.}
\end{document}
```

[image]